# Update custom filed in Moodle with web service?

Tags: web-services, moodle, moodle-api

I read API doc about how I can update phone1 (I suppose custom field because haven't documentation about my work-project) but I can't. There is an error(s).
Where is my error (an example)?

```
http://project.example.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=mytoken&wsfunction=core_user_update_users&users[0][id]=1392&customfields=(array(phone1=>123456789))
```

I tried 15/20 times (remove "array", removed "=>", ...) but without success!
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I try this (http://project.example.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=ba2cfac7a00b21b513a35027b4919769&wsfunction=core_user_update_users&users[0][id]=1392&users[0][customfields][0][type]=phone1&users[0][customfields][0][value]=123456789) but it is not correct

Comment: What exceptions (if any) are you seeing in the web server log?  Does the token have permission to do this action (site admin --> plugins --> web services --> manage tokens)?